# subprocess.call can't find file/shutil.which failed in pycharm

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, shutil

I am trying to transform a mp3 to a wav file in **pycharm** using subprocess

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i','test.mp3','test.wav'])
```

It returns error of not finding file, so I change the `'ffmpeg'` to its path on my pc and it work.

The problem is that I am making an app and others might install ffpmeg on other's location (since it is download with zip and can be unzip at any place), but I don't know how to get its full path.

I tried using `os` module

```
import os
print(os.path('ffmpeg.exe'))
```

but it seems like it is not able to get the path of exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Percy\PycharmProjects\APP\test3.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(os.path('ffmpeg.exe'))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I also tried `shutil` module

```
import shutil
print(shutil.which('ffmpeg'))
print(shutil.which('ffmpeg.exe'))
```

but it returns 2 None (prob wrong cause I am 100% sure I have installed ffmpeg)

```
None
None
```

I want to ask if there is any way to get the full path of ffmpeg in **pycharm** or any method that I can make ffmpeg install in designated path with the app when it is downloaded by users

Comment: This is on Windows? What was the .exe path? Unix based systems have common directories where binaries are stored and those directories are in the PATH variable. But Windows doesn't generally do that. Windows is 99% focused on running gui's by clicking on them or finding services via COM. It has never made finding .exe on PATH a priority. So, how did you install ffmpeg? Did it have an option for adding its directory to the PATH? You may need to make ffmpeg path a configuration option.

Comment: If the file isn't in the same folder of your program, it can't be see from it. You can try to give the complete path. If you're on Linux the generic path is something like "/home/%user%/folder/file", for windows "C:/path to the file/"

Comment: @alexlongo - for an executable called via subprocess, being in the same directory doesn't help. This is an operating system execution, not a python import. The file has to be in the path or use a qualified path. OP _did_ use the complete path, which works. But that is not a general solution.

Comment: `os.path` is a module that holds platform-specific file operations like `join` and `curdir`. `os.path('filename')` does not find files like `shutil.which(...)` does.

Comment: yes this is in window and the exe locate at document folder, but location for everyone is different i guess since the path on my pc is assign by me with winrar when I unzip the pack download from official site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can make "everyone" to install using my [`ffmpeg-downloader`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpeg-downloader) then all of you can install FFmpeg by:

```
pip install ffmpeg-downloader
ffdl install
```

Then in Python your package could use

```py
import ffmpeg_downloader as ffdl

sp.run([ffdl.ffmpeg_path, '-i', 'input.mp4', 'output.mkv'])
```

Alternately, you can use [`static-ffmpeg`](https://github.com/zackees/static_ffmpeg) to (dynamically) install FFmpeg to `Lib/site-package`. (See the linked GitHub page for howto.)